# ASP.NET MVC | ActionResult not getting called when going back to previous page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I understand that the title of the question may be vague but then that's the best way I could come up with to explain my issue at hand.

I'm overriding the `OnActionExecuting` function to manage my session related activities and allow/ deny requests to authorized/ unauthorized users, respectively. Along with tracking of the session, I'm also using the `OnActionExecuting` to load user available features for the current page into a temporary class and accessing from the view using ajax call.

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class TESTController : Controller
    {
        [SessionTimeout]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.View();
        }
    }
}

public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{         
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (ctx.Session["AppUser"] == null)
        {
            // Redirect to the login page
            // Or deny request
        }
        else
        {
            var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var methodType = ((ReflectedActionDescriptor)filterContext.ActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.ReturnType;

            if (methodType == typeof(ActionResult))
            {
                // Load all user access rights for the current page into a temporary memory
                // by using the Action and Controller name
            }                  
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The above works like a charm.. But the issue is when the user clicks on the back button of the browser or hits the backspace key. In that case, the `OnActionExecuting` function is never called for the ActionResult and further I am unable to load the current page access rights for the user.

Thanks & Regards,
Kshitij

Comment: Verify that the browser actually sends a request instead of showing the cached version.

Comment: Yes, I put up a breakpoint on the ActionResult of the "previous page". The browser is showing the cached version and just fetching the data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to my ActionResult made the above code to work.

```
    [SessionTimeout]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult SomeView()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
```